# Top misrepresentations in programming?

Tags: design-patterns, anti-patterns

I often find that design patterns, libraries, and frameworks promise great things and sound awesome - until you actually study them and realize that what they say sounds better than it actually is.

[Forklift Code http://xeoncross.com/images/funwithforklifts.jpg](http://xeoncross.com/images/funwithforklifts.jpg)

> *Completely modular and stackable - use
>   only what you need!*

For example, how do you properly Unit Test your database if your application is tightly coupled to a global database singleton? Singletons maybe all the rage in frameworks - but unless you're careful you will break [Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662842/dependency-injection-singleton-design-pattern) which is important for Unit Testing.

**What is the most misleading representation you want to warn your fellow programmers about?**

> *It’s kinda the same idea as facebook,
>   with functionality more like Twitter,
>   but with the innovation of Microsoft.*
>   - [clientsfromhell](http://xeoncross.com/images/funwithforklifts.jpg)

Comment: I think you should make this post a Community Wiki before the downvoters notices.

Comment: If you're referring to design patterns as a whole. I don't think you understand what design patterns are for and how/when to use them.

Comment: misrepresentation?  misleading?  Spelling aside, I love the image!

Comment: Are you looking for anti-patterns?

Comment: Don't listen to Miss Information!  She'll lead you astray.

Comment: @Byron no, just examples of design ideas/patterns that are more danger than help.

Comment: This is highly subjective.  Lots of people seem to intentionally misinterpret the simplest things.  Fully half the questions on SO amount to: "I think X should do Y, how do I make that work?"  Was the person lied to (as implied by your question) or did they intentionally misrepresent what they were told?

Comment: Anything that promises great improvements in productivity is overhyped. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet