# How to write singleton node module across files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is probably a dumb question but i wanted to clarify this things to my self and get other opinions about it.

Let's say i have a node file `x.js` like this.

```
var x=0;
module.exports = init = function(someValue){
     if(someValue)
        x=someValue;
}
init.prototype.getX = function(){
    return x;
}
```

And let's say i've `y.js` like this.

```
var X = require('x')(10);
X.getX() //this will return 10 right?
```

But my question is this, if i have `z.js` file with the following content.

```
var X = require('x')();
//what will x.getX(); returns?
```

do it return 10, because 10 is set on `y.js` file or 0?

In what way should i write the code to make it singleton across files(without database if it is possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node JS cache modules so everytime same module will be loaded as node JS already wraps all the modules in singletons.

So, yes `z.js` will return 10 provided you have already loaded `y.js`

If you really want to use singleton( [why not dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662842/dependency-injection-singleton-design-pattern)) then this is a good way to go.

**Update** : As I see you are exporting constructor, so you will have to use new keyword, changing your `y.js` to

```
var X = require('x')(10);
var instanceOfX = new X();
instanceOfX.getX() //this will return 10 definitely and focus on new operator
```

and update `z.js` similarly

Comment: i think it should be something like this `var X = require('x');  var x = new X();` then `x.getX()` . update your answer accordingly and i'll accept is as an answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer it was really helpful.